# Java Rest Service POST disagree on InnerClasses attribute

Tags: java, rest, post, cors, jax-rs

I have a REST service written in Java. I have a GET method which is working perfectly and now I want to implement the POST method.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void post(String ext){
    System.out.println("In the POST method");
    System.out.println(ext);
}
```

Also I have a CORS Filter because I'm working on the localhost and sending stuff on the localhost.

```
Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                  final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
} 
}
```

As soon as I add a parameter in the POST method I get the following error:

```
WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.movierestservice.resources.MoviesResource$CORSFilter] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.movierestservice.resources.MoviesResource and com.movierestservice.resources.MoviesResource$CORSFilter disagree on InnerClasses attribute
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1235)
at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1277)
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1443)
at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Class.java:1433)
```

etc ....

When I remove the parameter at the POST method everything is fine. Anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you have the filter as an inner class? Put it in it's own class file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That `IncompatibleClassChangeError` probably means you have stale (old) `.class` files in your classpath. You need to recompile the project from scratch. Use "Clean project" or "Rebuild project" commands in your IDE or just delete the output directory (`build` or `out` or smth. like that).

And make sure you have enabled "make project before run" setting in your IDE.

Comment: @RSSD if you've found the answer useful, please accept and upvote.